# How can I prove that this operator is not hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, hermitian-matrices

In a prehilbert space $E$ of finite dimension $n$ I have an operator $A$ and an orthonormal basis formed by $n$ vectors: $(v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$. $A$ is defined such that:

$A(v_i) = v_{i-1}$ for $i = 2, ..., n$ and $A(v_1) = v_1$ for $i = 1$.

The question is, how can I prove that this operator is not hermitian? My first course of action was to figure out the matrix associated to the operator and directly find out if the property holds; however,  I've been having trouble identifying it since as you can see the operator isn't as simple as, say: $G(x, y) = (2x, x+y)$. This last example has a clear-cut matrix, but the $A$ operator in my problem is much more confusing to me. Any help in finding this matrix or generally finding a proof for it not being hermitian is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hermitian operator has to satisfy
$$\langle x,A y\rangle = \langle A x, y\rangle.$$
However, if you choose $x = v_1$ and $y = v_2$. You would have
$$\langle x,A y\rangle = \langle v_1, v_1\rangle = 1.$$ On the other hand,
$$\langle A x, y\rangle = \langle v_1, v_2\rangle = 0.$$
Therefore, $A$ is non-Hermitian.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that property (or, rather, writing the property in terms of a scalar product) is not in my notes, but it's good to know, so thanks!